# Finding the number of Polysyllables in java

Tags: arrays, string, count

Say I have a String array, I already counted the number of syllables in the array. How would I go about finding the number of Polysyllables in the array? I know I would have to count the number of words with syllables > 1, but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Comment: So... what have you tried? And, which language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of the number of syllables in another data structure. You could use a simple `int[]` to do this, and it could be returned by the function that counts syllables, that you have already created.

```
String[] myStrings = {"One", "Syllable", "Dog", "Laptop"};
int[] mySyllables = countSyllables(myStrings);
//In the above case, mySyllables = {1, 3, 1, 2};
```

So once you have counted the number of syllables, and saved the values, you can iterate your `mySyllables` array, and whenever you encounter a value greater than 1, you know how many polysyllables you have.

```
int numPoly = 0;
for(int i=0;i<mySyllables.length;i++) {
    if(mySyllables[i] > 1) numPoly++;
}
```

In the given sample case, the end result is `numPoly == 2`, being "Syllables" and "Laptop"

Comment: I tried your method but for some reason, it is giving me 0 for the number of polysyllables...

Comment: Trying printing every value in the mySyllables array and making sure that there are values greater than one, otherwise numPoly will always be zero.

Comment: Everything in mySyllables is zero. "int[] mySyllables = countSyllables(myStrings);" is giving me a problem since my code is reading from a URL.

Comment: The countSyllables method you've posted only returns int, not int[]. Change this and then test manually with simple cases to make sure it's working correctly.